# Share Image to app using monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How to Enable Share Image VIA my APP using Monodroid ?
I am using this piece of code in order to have a share to my app menu in android gallery application.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="TestRun!">
    <activity android:name=".ImageFromGallery">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
```

`Effects :` 
Two Application icon appears on the menu.
A share button is added in gallery.
Can any one provide me with sample code ?
I Debugged the application `ImageFromGallery` activity never get called.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Perfect Example for You.

http://eggie5.com/8-hook-share-picture-via-menu-android

Comment: thanks for the example. I am following the same example, but can you please point out the example using monodroid. i have no experience with java, the problem is i have difficulty in convertin this code for monodroid

Comment: Give it a try! You'll find porting that code quite straightforward and experiencing a bit of java will make you a much better monodroid coder - it'll open up so many additional resources to you.

Comment: What we probably will need is what error it throws and maybe a what you are doing with the app when it receives the intent.

Answer (score 0):

The solution Bhavin posted is great if you're doing it on android but you need to add the two following lines about your class:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity label", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
[IntentFilter(new[]{Intent.ActionSend},Categories = new[]{Intent.CategoryDefault},DataMimeType = "image/*",Label = "Your application name")]
```

Then after that you can handle the image information however you'd like and the manner told on the link Bhavin posted is a solid way to do it.